# regex to verify url?

Tags: python, regex

Could anyone help with regex?
I have an URL like

```
"http://example.com/ru/path/?id=1234&var=abcd"
```

I'd like an assertion that checks that the URL has a stucture:

```
"http://example.com/ru/path/?id={id value}&var={var value}"
```

Comment: You could [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely regex is overkill. if it's repeatable like that you could use:

```
url="http://example.com/ru/path/?id=1234&var=abcd"
if url.split('?')[1].startswith('id=') and url.split('&')[1].startswith('var='):
    print "yay!"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s="http://example.com/ru/path/?id=1234&var=abcd"
pattern = r'http:\/\/example.com\/ru\/path\/\?id=\d+&var=\w+'
res = re.findall(patten,s)
if res:
   print "yes:
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex isn't needed but using regex just check that there is a digit (`\d+`) and a var (`[A-z]+`)

```
import re
p = re.compile('http://example.com/ru/path/\?id=\d+&var=[A-z]+')

check=p.match("http://example.com/ru/path/?id=1234&var=abcd")

if check:
    print 'match'
else:
    print 'does not match'
```